PlatformIO extension not installing
This may be a general extensions issue, but it occurred when I tried to install PlatformIO.
Clicking "install" switches the state to "installed" and flips the button to "uninstall", however no installation scripts run (like attempting to install the PlatformIO CLI, etc.) no restart notification.
I have not seen any errors when viewing the debug console, however I do see an empty "Extension Host" object.

Is there some global configuration or permission, or worker thread preventing the extension install from kicking off?

To proceed, you must first ascertain the extent of the issue. Should it be confined to the PlatformIO extension, the developers of the extension would be the most appropriate point of contact for such inquiries, https://github.com/platformio/platformio-vscode-ide/issues

So you're saying the first step in troubleshooting this issue would be to solve it?

I have solved the installation issue. Apparently there is some update or variation in environment where the installation for PlatformIO CLI does not complete until I click on the alien head in the left margin.

Once I did that the remaining installation steps continued as expected and I could use the extension.
Suggest the installation instructions be updated with this nuance.
https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/integration/ide/vscode.html#installation
